# How can I stack/pile point layers within administrative areas with qgis

Tags: qgis, symbology, point, visualisation, zoom

How can I stack/pile point layers within administrative areas with QGIS. Close points (categorized) should not overlap in zoomed out map (and lose their position).

Please see the visualization of cooperatives in Berlin or Hamburg in the following example:

Example:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

One approach I can think of is to use a MMQGIS plugin which will then provide you with the option of to use "Gridify", this will place the points to a grid.

You will have to tweak things a bit until it looks the way you want it to be using the categorize style.